# appcelerator is not creating IPA file

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipa

I have updated my Xcode to latest  version, Now I am unable to generate my IPA file. I tried several method but did not get any luck. 
I have tried with 5.1 and latest SDK as well.
If any idea then let me know.

Comment: Do you really think that providing this much little info in your question will help anyone solve your problem? First of all, while writing any question, always provide the necessary info someone might need to fix your query.

Comment: In this question, provide the info like how you are creating the IPA file, and what's the output on console is showing up?

Comment: provide  what warning or log file showing in ur Xcode..?

Answer (score 0):

I think your Ti SDK version and Xcode version is not compatible. Try to use Ti SDK 6.0.0.GA and later version for the latest Xcode. Please check out the following compatible matrix

- http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Titanium_Compatibility_Matrix-section-src-29004837_TitaniumCompatibilityMatrix-Xcode

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, but still it is not working. I am using 
Xcode version - 8.3.1
Appcelrator version - 4.8.1.2016
SDK version - 5.5.1 used above versions also

i am able to run my app in device but not find .ipa file in folder i don't know where i am going wrong pls help me...

Comment: I see it's an issue for the recent Xcode version, .ipa file is not created to the Debug-iphoneos folder. So you can create ad-hoc builds. Please take a look this Jira ticket have some info in the comment - https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-24557